How to add ".html" to links?
Use Pelican 4.1, everything is running fine.
Used Google Search Console and it's complaining about links are not canonical."Alternate page with Canonical tag"
The reason seems to be I'm using Markdown links:
* [Setup](/setup-common) - some text

Which get translated by Pelican to html links:
<li><a href="/setup-common">Setup</a> - some text</li>

Note the href here does not have the ".html" suffix.
But the generated setup-common page has this line:
<link href="https://10.0.0.10/setup-common.html" rel="canonical"/>

The "canonical" tag indicates this href link has the canonical way of calling this page. But the href here has ".html" in it.
I believe the discrepancy between this link and the previous one is causing the Search Console warnings.
Adding the ".html" to my markdown files causes a bunch of other issues and so I'd like to not do that. Is there some pelicanconf.py setting I can use to have Pelican automatically add the ".html" to all links parsed in all markdown files?
